# Bracket checker

Tags: java, while-loop, stack, brackets

So this code is supposed to take user input and see if the brackets are balanced. The instructions just say use a while loop to input multiple lines and print "Exit program". My question: I'm not sure how to break out of the while loop after a few lines of input so that sout("Exit program") will be called - everything else works fine.
PS. still very new to this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class BracketChecker {
    private Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

    public boolean check(String text) {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if (c == '{') {
                stack.push(c);
            }

            if (c == '}'){
                if (stack.empty())
                    return false;
                stack.pop();
            }
        }

        if (stack.isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting bracket checker app");
        BracketChecker checker = new BracketChecker();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String temp;
        while(in.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = in.nextLine();

            if (checker.check(temp)) {
                System.out.println("Syntax correct");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Syntax error");
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Exiting checker");
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly asking: Is this for an assignment? If yes, how is the user supposed to end the program? `in.hasNextLine()` for the user input will always return `true` (I think).

Comment: Also in the `check` methode, you should clear the stack at the end if it is not empty or unless the next call will not work properly

Comment: Your code inserted in [tio.run](https://tio.run/#java-openjdk) (with minor changes to the class name) works as expected. So please describe you problem in more detail.

Comment: @Ackdari it is yes, and nothing about how the program is supposed to end is specified

Comment: @Ackdari it is an infinite loop and I'm wondering how to break out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define somekind of stop command like `stop`, then check if you read this command and if yes end the program:

```java
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
    temp = in.nextLine();

    if ("stop".equals(temp)) {
        System.out.println("Exiting checker");
        return;
    }

    if (checker.check(temp)) {
        System.out.println("Syntax correct");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Syntax error");
    }
}

System.out.println("Error");
```

you will also need to change the last part of the `check` method:

```java
if (stack.isEmpty()){
    return true;
}
else{
    stack.clear();
    return false;
}
```

this way the stack is always empty at the end of the `check` method.

Then input like

```
{{
{}
stop
```

will procude the following output

```
Starting bracket checker app
Syntax error
Syntax correct
Exiting checker
```

But since this is for an assigment you should check with your tutor or lecturer how you are supposed to end the program

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop:

```
 while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        temp = in.nextLine();

        if (checker.check(temp)) {
            System.out.println("Syntax correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Syntax error");
        }

    }
```

will result in an infinite loop, if you wanted to you could have the user input an int to the amount of times they want to input like

```
int amount = scanner.nextInt();
```

and the using the amount in a for loop. Also you can change the part:

```
if (stack.isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```

to just be return stack.isEmpty();

Comment: The last part is not correct, if the previous input had more opening brackets then closing the next string will be reported as wrong even if it is correct